# fit_transform vs transform when doing inference

Tags: keras, scikit-learn

I have trained a keras model and saved it. I now want to use the model in a web app for inference. I want to preprocess the inputs by scaling them using `StandardScaler()` from sklearn.
But whenever i run `transform(inputs)` an error occurs wanting me to do fitting first. This was the code

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
inputs = [1,8,0,0,4,18,4,3,576,9,8,8,14,1,0,4,0,0,3,6,0,1,1]
inputs = scale.transform(inputs)
preds = model.predict(inputs, batch_size = 1)
```

I then changed the code inorder to do fitting

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    inputs = [1,8,0,0,4,18,4,3,576,9,8,8,14,1,0,4,0,0,3,6,0,1,1]
    inputs = scale.fit_transform(inputs)
    preds = model.predict(inputs, batch_size = 1)
```

It worked but the scaled data are all bunch of zeros regardless of the inputs i provide, making wrong predicitions. Am certain am missing some key concepts here, i am asking for help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The standard scaler function has formula:

```
z = (x - u) / s
```

Here,

```
x: Element  
u: Mean  
s: Standard Deviation
```

This element transformation is done column-wise.
Therefore, when you call to fit the values of `mean` and `standard_deviation` are calculated.

Eg:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(50,size = (10,2))
x
```

Output:

```
array([[26,  9],
       [29, 39],
       [23, 26],
       [29, 22],
       [28, 41],
       [11,  6],
       [42, 40],
       [ 1, 25],
       [ 0, 39],
       [44, 45]])
```

Now, fitting the standard scaler

```
scale = StandardScaler()
scale.fit(x)
```

You can see the mean and standard deviation using the built methods for the `StandardScaler` object

```
# Mean
scale.mean_   # array([23.3, 29.2])

# Standard Deviation
scale.scale_  # array([14.36697602, 13.12859475])
```

You transform these values using the transform method.

```
scale.transform(x)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0.18793099, -1.53862621],
       [ 0.3967432 ,  0.74646222],
       [-0.02088122, -0.24374277],
       [ 0.3967432 , -0.54842122],
       [ 0.32713913,  0.89880145],
       [-0.85613006, -1.76713506],
       [ 1.3015961 ,  0.82263184],
       [-1.55217075, -0.31991238],
       [-1.62177482,  0.74646222],
       [ 1.44080424,  1.20347991]])
```

Calculation for 1st element:

```
z = (26 - 23.3) /  14.36697602
z = 0.18793099
```

**How to use this?**
The transformation should be done before training your model. The training should be done on transformed data. And for the prediction, the test data should use the same mean and standard deviation values as your training data. ie. Do not use `fit` method on the test data. You should use the object that was used to transform the training data to transform your test data.